# html changes won't show up in browser

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an assignment for a class where our teacher has given us a webpage built out with html and css. We are eventually supposed to create some animations with gsap, but first need to make our own edits to the webpage itself. I am using vscode and when I edit any of the html, the changes show up in my index.html, but not in the browser. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Hello, are you just working with html and css without a local server? If not you will try disable your browser caché and also start the index.html from VS code ( on the top click Run>Start debugging>Choose your browser

Answer (score 0):

try to right click your browser and check in the sources to make sure it really saved your changes.

Comment: right click inspect -> source

Comment: ok so I did that and in the browser the changes aren't saved. but they are saved in vscode so I don't understand why they aren't translating to the browser

Comment: did you try to reopen your browser?

Comment: if you are very new at this you might not know that you need to refresh your browser after you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, and the solution was very stupid. I was working on multiple files in a folder and the next day i tried modifying only one file while opening the single file itself. and solution was that I must open the entire folder in my editor which is vs code by clicking file->open folder. and then open my desired file from the list it displays for me. and done ! the changes are saved.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use live server on VS Code and then whenever you save it will show up on the page.

-> https://techstacker.com/local-live-server-vscode/

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you save the file and reload the page in the browser